# Flutter | How to display records in datatable of the current when redirected to the screen

Tags: flutter, datatable, dropdown

i am trying to display the current month in dropdown by default ( by the word default i mean when user redirect to the the screen dropdown will display the current month and table will display the that current month records.) So, i am displaying the current month but my data table is not displaying the records.

I am passing the month (in number) in my api body, i defined a list which contains months list when user select the month then i am getting its index and increment it by 1 as my list index starts from 0, and then passing that number which is my month to my api.

here is the code

```
String _selectedMonth;
int monthIndex;
int month;

var monthsList=<String>[
      'January',
      'Febuary',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'Augest',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December'
  ];

  String getdate="";
    void _getDate() {
    final String formattedDateTime =
        DateFormat('MM').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    _selectedMonth=DateFormat('MMMM').format(DateTime.now());
    setState(() {
      getdate = formattedDateTime;
      print(currentmonth);
     print("date  "+getdate);
    });
  }
   void initState() {
      _userDetails();
      _getDate();
      _getRecord(); 
  }

 Future<List<History>> _getRecord() async{
   Dio dio=new Dio();
   var data={
     'username':getName,
     'month':month,
     'token':getaccesstoken
   };
   return dio
    .post(localhostUrlAttendanceHistory,data: json.encode(data))
      .then((onResponse) async {
        Map<String, dynamic> map=onResponse.data;     
        List<dynamic> data = map['data'];
 
        for (var h in data) {
          History history = History(
            h["_id"],
            h["Date"], 
            h["TimeIn"], 
            h["TimeOut"],
          );
          historyList.add(history);
          id=history.id.toString();
          print("id is ");
          print(id);
        }
        return historyList;
      })
      .catchError((onerror){
        print(onerror.toString());
       
    });
  }

//datatable code

 Widget attendanceHistory(List<History> 
    historyList)=> 
   Center(
     child:Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 18, 0),
      child:SingleChildScrollView(
         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,          
           child:DataTable(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue[500], width: 2)),
          headingRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.blue[500]),
          headingTextStyle: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
          showBottomBorder: true,
          headingRowHeight: 60,
          horizontalMargin: 7,
          columnSpacing: 15,      
          dataRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.blue[50]),
          dividerThickness: 4,        
          columns: <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(label: Text("Date")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Time in")),
        DataColumn(label: Text("Time out"),numeric: true),
        DataColumn(label: Text("   Edit")),
    ],
    rows:     
    historyList
      ?.map((element)=>DataRow(
        selected: true ,
      cells: <DataCell>[
      DataCell(Text(element?.date),),
      DataCell(Text(element?.timeIn)),
      DataCell(Text(element?.timeOut,)),
      DataCell(IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.edit,color: Colors.blue,),onPressed: (){
        _getSelectedRowInfo(element?.id,element?.date,element?.timeIn,element?.timeOut);
      })


void _getSelectedRowInfo(dynamic id,dynamic date,dynamic timein,dynamic timeout) {
  
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(  
    scrollable: true, 
    insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50),
    title: Text("Request to change time",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.blue[500])),  
    
    content:Container(child: SingleChildScrollView( 
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child:Column(children:<Widget> [     
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: date,hintText: "Date"),
        controller:dateController ,
        
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: timein,hintText: "Time in",icon: Icon(Icons.timer)),
        controller:timeinController ,
        readOnly:true,
        onTap: () async {
                  TimeOfDay pickedTime =  await showTimePicker(
                          initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                          context: context,
                      );
        if(pickedTime != null ){
                      print(pickedTime.format(context));   //output 10:51 PM
                      DateTime parsedTime = DateFormat.jm().parse(pickedTime.format(context).toString());
                      //converting to DateTime so that we can further format on different pattern.
                      print(parsedTime); //output 1970-01-01 22:53:00.000
                      String formattedTime = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss').format(parsedTime);
                      print(formattedTime); //output 14:59:00
                      //DateFormat() is from intl package, you can format the time on any pattern you need.

                      setState(() {
                        timeinController.text = formattedTime; //set the value of text field. 
                      });
                  }else{
                      print("Time is not selected");
                  }
                },
      ),
      TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText:timeout,hintText: "Time out",icon: Icon(Icons.timer_off)),
        controller:timeoutController ,
        readOnly:true,
        onTap: () async {
                  TimeOfDay pickedTime =  await showTimePicker(
                          initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                          context: context,
                      );
        if(pickedTime != null ){
                      print(pickedTime.format(context));   //output 10:51 PM
                      DateTime parsedTime = DateFormat.jm().parse(pickedTime.format(context).toString());
                      //converting to DateTime so that we can further format on different pattern.
                      print(parsedTime); //output 1970-01-01 22:53:00.000
                      String formattedTime = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss').format(parsedTime);
                      print(formattedTime); //output 14:59:00
                      //DateFormat() is from intl package, you can format the time on any pattern you need.

                      setState(() {
                        timeoutController.text = formattedTime; //set the value of text field. 
                      });
                  }else{
                      print("Time is not selected");
                  }
                },
      ),
      
     ]), 
  )
  
  ),

  actions: [  
      FlatButton(  
    child: Text("Submit",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.blue[500],fontSize: 20),),  
    onPressed: () { 

    getupdatedTime();
    Dio dio=new Dio();
        var data={
          'id': id,
          'token':getaccesstoken,
          'TimeIn': timeinText,
          'TimeOut':timeoutText,
          
        };
        print("token is "+getaccesstoken);
        print("submit id is  "+id);
        print(data);
        dio
        .put(localhostUrlMarkCorrection, data: json.encode(data))
          .then((onResponse) async {
            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog');
            dialoguebox();

            print("mark correction");
            print(onResponse.data);
            print(onResponse.statusCode);
            
            
          }).catchError((onerror){
            print(onerror.toString());
        });
      }
      
    )],  
  );  
      showDialog(  
      context: context,  
      builder: (BuildContext context) {  
        return alert;  
      },  
    );  
      
}


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new MyAppBar(title: Text("My Attendance"),onpressed: (){
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Profile()));
   }),
    
    drawer:Emp_DrawerCode(),
   
    body:Stack(children: <Widget>[
//here is my dropdown code
        Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 80, 10, 0),
        child:
        DropdownButton<String>(
        value: _selectedMonth==null?null:monthsList[monthIndex],    
        items: 
          monthsList   
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value)
            );
          }).toList(),
          hint:Text(
            "Please choose a month",
          ),
          onChanged: (String value) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedMonth=value;  //i am getting month here 
              monthIndex = monthsList.indexOf(value);  //then getting its index, so that i can find month in number
              month=monthIndex+1;  //and as index start from 0 so i increment it by 1
              print(month);
              print(_selectedMonth);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),

class History {
  final String id;
  final String date;
  final String timeIn;
  final String timeOut;
  

  History(this.id,this.date, this.timeIn, this.timeOut);

}
```

**Outputs:**

When i enter into screen it looks like this

**Pic 1:**
[image]

and when i select month from dropdown it is displaying records.

**Pic 2:**
[image]

i want output like Pic 2 when i am redirect/enter into screen, and then user can also select the month from dropdown and table rows will modify according to select month.

Please help if anyone know how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean that the rows of the tables are not shown when entering the page but shown after you rebuild it for some other reason? I don't understand well the question

Comment: yes, when i am entering into the page rows are not shown, when i select the month from dropdown then my data table is display the records.

Comment: i update my question with output, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some weird things on your code. But the main problem is that month is null.

You can use getters to calculate when required (removing old variables) .

```dart
  int get monthIndex => return monthsList.indexOf(_selectedMonth);

  int get month => monthIndex + 1;
```

You can also try to calculate it again at the initState before performing the operation both ways should fix your bug.

Some weird behaviour I can see is that `_selectedMonth` is writen at _getDate and initState.

I don't see where `historyList` is created but maybe you need to instantiate it at `_getRecord`.

And this if will always be false `if(monthsList.contains("element"))` as there is no month called `"element"`.